# How to calculate probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that you spin a dial that freely moves  marked out in 360 degrees in steps of 5 degrees. Whats the proability that the dial will land somewhere between 5 degrees and 300 degrees. Al so how do you calculate the answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(\{\text{"land between 5º and 300º"}\})}{\mathbb{P}(\{\text{"land anywhere"}\})} = 1 - \frac{\mathbb{P}(\{\text{"land between 300º and 5º"}\})}{\mathbb{P}(\{\text{"land anywhere"}\})} = \\ = 1 - \frac{65/5}{360/5} = 1 - 13/72 = 59/72$$
Note: landing between 5º and 300º is different from landing between 300º and 5º because of the orientation

Comment: Thank you but that dident work still getting incorrect answer

Comment: I think it is right now, I had done the calculations wrong :/